# CSS selector for non-html attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know for standard html attributes there are CSS selectors:
`span[class="example"]`

But I would like to know if there are selectors for CSS attributes, e.g.
`span[background-image]`.
?

*Update:*
After reading some of the comments and answers so far, I better give a reason for this "strange" need. I would like to find all elements that have background-image set to anything other than undefined/empty, to apply style to them. The assumption is that I cannot control the existing inline/global styles, only add my own global style sheet.

Comment: There's a meme in this question.. :)

Comment: @valentinas, what do you mean?

Comment: Those are CSS properties, not attributes. And no, you cannot use CSS to select elements by their computed or declared styles. How would that make sense?

Comment: @BoltClock I updated the question, but what you say makes sense.

Comment: @Alex, I meant "Yo dawg.." and "We need to go deeper" :) On the more related note: could you elaborate what are you trying to achieve? Maybe there are other ways to do it, without selecting elements with background-image, e.g. if you want to remove all background images then you only need to do * {background-image:none}. The same applies if you want to change image position, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

It would be too expensive a rule for the browser to look up. As you are most likely setting the background-image in other css classes, it would be fairly straightforward to target them explicitly (also, not by using **span[class="example"]** but **span.example** instead)

Also, as you noted in the comments to another answer, rules of the type

```
span[style*="background-image"]​{}​
```

would only apply to inline styles, and you're in for a nightmare if you're looking them up by value like so

```
span[style*="background-image: url(potato.png)"]​{}​
```

*Is the background set explicitly or through a shorthand property like **background:#fff url(potato.png);** Did I enter a space there or not? Capitalization, maybe it's **.PNG**?*

Answer (score 1):

You could check for inline styles:

```
span[style*="background-image"]​{}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvtvf/)

Comment: it does work well for inline styles (FF10) but seems not to work for global styles

Answer (score 0):

Try inline css method.

```
span[style="background-image:url('YourImagePAth')]
```